# Is there any replacement for OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods in new Spring Scurity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I can't manage with upgrading my spring libs to latest version. Now spring security supports Oauth2 in one main package.
In old Spring Oauth2 I was able to use isClient or isUser from
`org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods` to allow or forbid requests.

example:

```
    @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.isClient()")
```

Now whole package org.springframework.security.oauth2 is marked as deprecated.
Can someone give my adivce how I can achive the same result using news Spring Security?

Comment: This article might help https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide not an expert on oauth myself though

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read all over documentation available in the internet. In your link there is example based on an expression: access("#oauth2.hasScope('scope')"). But oauth2.hasScope is not available in spring dependencies. I think they didn't edited documentation in those places. Take a look
spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this security config to your pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It enables  @PreAuthorize() annotation from this import

```
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
```

Comment: Thank you for response but I think you misunderstood question. It is not question about PreAuthorize annotation but rather about where Can I find methods isClient and isUser